# Will aurelia-fetch support polyfill?

Tags: fetch, aurelia, polyfills

Is there a plan to add **polyfill** support to the **aurelia-fetch** module, and if so when will it become available?  We started with this module but now realize that Safari doesn't have support for fetch yet (except in the tech preview version), so I thought I'd check before changing to whatwg-fetch or fetch.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use fetch polyfill directly. Just include some polyfill like [GitHub `fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch) **in addition** to `aurelia-fetch-client`.

If you are using jspm, then `jspm install fetch` and add import to `main` module:

```
import 'fetch';
```

After that, you can use `aurelia-fetch-client` with all browsers. More info in [documentation hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/2).

Also, as Daniel mentioned in comment, once the browser adoption is better, you can just remove polyfill without affecting the application.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that not using a tightly coupled polyfill has the advantage that you can swap it out if there's any better at some time. :-)